# mysqli_multi_query - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

I have several query strings which I want to execute at once using "mysqli_multi_query". This works.

When I insert a query again to check each item in joined tables using "mysqli_query" it doesn't return any result **nor** any error from PHP. When I run the query string manually in phpmyadmin, everything works fine as it should.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$connect   = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
$strquery  = "";
$strquery .= "1st Query";
$strquyer .= "2nd Query";
if($multi = mysqli_multi_query($connect,$strquery)){   // function mysqli_multi_query is working
     // From here it doesn't give any response
     $qryarray = mysqli_query($connect, 
                              "SELECT purchase_detail_$_SESSION[period].item_code,
                                      purchase_detail_$_SESSION[period].location_code
                               FROM   purchase_detail_$_SESSION[period] 
                               WHERE  purchase_detail_$_SESSION[period].purchase_num = '$_POST[purchase_num]' 
                               UNION
                               SELECT purchase_detail_temp.item_code,
                                      purchase_detail_temp.location_code
                               FROM   purchase_detail_temp 
                               WHERE  purchase_detail_temp.purchase_num = '$_POST[purchase_num]' AND purchase_detail_temp.username = '$_SESSION[username]'");
     while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($qryarray)){
          "Some code to process several item code in table purchase_detail_$_SESSION[period]"
     }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you write how your query should be? I am pretty sure the query is wrong the way it is created.

Comment: You need a semicolon between the two queries.

Comment: When `mysqli_mylti_query()` fails, you should `echo mysqli_error()` to see the reason.

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: @Nikos : the first and second query above are working, database have changed as well as the query tell, the problem is after mysqli_multi_query() the query in $qryarray variable

Comment: @Barmar : mysqli_multi_array() works fine and the result is like what I want.. The problem is after mysqli_multi_array() function...

Comment: @Fred-ii- : sure I start the session, if I don't the query above won't work at all...

Comment: Is `mysqli_query()` getting an error?

Comment: it doesn't give any error comment in the page.. it just a blank screen like nothing happens after mysqli_multi_query()

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()` if you haven't already, and error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: thanks now the error show up, it says `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just found the answer in [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#102837):

> WATCH OUT: if you mix `$mysqli->multi_query` and `$mysqli->query`, the
> latter(s) won't be executed!
>
> BAD CODE:
>
> ```
> $mysqli->multi_query(" Many SQL queries ; "); // OK
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #1 ; ") // not executed!
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #2 ; ") // not executed!
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #3 ; ") // not executed!
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #4 ; ") // not executed!
> ```
>
> The only way to do this correctly is:
>
> WORKING CODE:
>
> ```
> $mysqli->multi_query(" Many SQL queries ; "); // OK
> while ($mysqli->next_result()) {;} // flush multi_queries
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #1 ; ") // now executed!
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #2 ; ") // now executed!
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #3 ; ") // now executed!
> $mysqli->query(" SQL statement #4 ; ") // now executed!
> ```

I just insert this code after `mysqli_multi_query()`:

```
while(mysqli_next_result($connect)){;}
```

Comment: MySQL spits error:  .... mysqli::next_result(): There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method ....  in  if I use your method with while ($mysqli->next_result())

Comment: @Thanasis This worked for me: while ($mysqli->more_results()) {$mysqli->next_result();}

Answer (score 10):

As addition to Edison's answer:

> while(mysqli_next_result($connect)){;}

I would recommend this code. This avoids exceptions.

```
while(mysqli_more_results($con))
{
   mysqli_next_result($con);
}
```

Comment: while(mysqli_more_results($mysqli)){mysqli_next_result($mysqli);}