# WordPress database error Commands out of sync;

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I made a Wordpress plugin that imports some products (few hundreds) from API to Woocommerce. The problem is that after about 10 minutes (max execution time is set to unlimited) I'm getting this error multiple times with option_name different (there are some taxonomies for attributes):

```
WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query SELECT autoload FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_transient_wc_layered_nav_counts_pa_tehnologii-display' made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Cache_Helper::delete_transients_on_shutdown, delete_transient, delete_option
```

In other moments, the job which is importing products is stopping without any error message.

I tried the plugin on other hosts and no problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try this: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31245#comment:57 it seems related

Comment: did you find a solution ? if you did please share it here

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it happened because of the conflicts between `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_multi_query` when I was developing [my own WP+React template](https://github.com/sainthkh/wp-react-plugin-boilerplate).

According to [this doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php#102837) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899598/mysqli-multi-query-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now), it can cause "commands of sync" error.

In WordPress Database class, `wpdb`, [it uses `mysqli_query`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4a958b82c2c73b22e6b845bcd09b45a4dcf103f8/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L2050-L2071). And I used `mysqli_multi_query` for my SQL code. They caused exactly the problem in the above 2 documents.

The solution was described in the document, too.

I fixed it by adding the line below:

```php
$result = mysqli_multi_query($wpdb->dbh, $sql);
while(mysqli_next_result($wpdb->dbh)); // flush multi queries.
```

ps. I also learned that when an error message starts with "WordPress database error", it means the error came from the database side (mysql), not the WordPress side. [Check this code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4a958b82c2c73b22e6b845bcd09b45a4dcf103f8/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1483). It can be helpful to search the error message with `mysql` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cache plugins error, try clearing your cache to see if it helps. otherwise completely uninstall and reinstall the cache plugin, maybe that will work. its caused by when a plugin leaves mess in database queries or doesnt close properly.

Also worth noting if your hosting is providing you the cache functionality and than you can safely disable the wordpress cache plugins.

Comment: actually it doesn't happen all the time and I don't know when does this error happen!

Answer (score 0):

In our case the problem was only on the database side.
We manage to solve the issue using cPanel "Repair Database" functionality.

[image: cPanel Database section]

In the section "Modify Databases" we selected the database and than click on "Repair database" button.